# center parameter is not defined in creating a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coords

I'm making a map and i want the map to zoom into my location but i get the error as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". Does anybody know what's wrong? please help me! Thank you so much!

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        
        #map {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='map'></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my JS:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGh0NzZkeThjIiwiYSI6ImNrdjd0Zm92cDF4aGMyb2wwenhtbWJidjUifQ.KUBtTY1kI2SOMFXkKeerWQ';

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successLocation, errorLocation, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
})

function successLocation(position) {
    console.log(position)
    setupMap([position.coords.longtitude, position.coords.latitude])
}

function errorLocation() {

}

function setupMap(center) {
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
        center: center
    });
}
```

Comment: This looks like you are not using Google Maps.  Why is it tagged `[google-maps]`?  What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: Typo, you are missing a coma after the `style` attribute (before the `center` attribute)...

Comment: @geocodezip add as answer?

Comment: i did add a comma after the style, it seemed to be rendered out but there's nowhere i can see the map, all i could see is a pointer on the screen